# Pull To Refresh (Chris Banes Plugin) In Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, eclipse-plugin, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to use pull to refresh in a fragment but not list fragment.
When the lines of the pull to refresh are notes the app works but when I bring them back I get this error:

```
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maperffecto/com.example.maperffecto.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:327)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at com.example.maperffecto.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    ... 11 more
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at com.example.maperffecto.FirstFragment.onCreateView(FirstFragment.java:52)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:879)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1053)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1155)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4858)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
01-27 12:13:15.656: E/AndroidRuntime(25130):    ... 21 more
```

And this is my fragment:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

private Button btnByText;
private Button btnByLocation;
private onSendToSecond listener;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
LocationHelper helper;
public interface onSendToSecond{
    public void sendData(String data);      
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment_layout, container, false);
    btnByText = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnByText);
    btnByLocation = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnByLocation);
    btnByText.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnByLocation.setOnClickListener(this);

    helper = new LocationHelper(getActivity(), "LocationDb.db", null, 1);
    Cursor c = helper.getLocation();

    String [] from = new String [] {helper.LOCATION_COL, helper.ADDRESS_COL, helper.DISTANCE_COL};
    int [] to = new int [] {R.id.txtLocation, R.id.txtAddress, R.id.txtDistance, R.id.imglocation};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_layout, c, from, to, 2);

    PullToRefreshListView list = (PullToRefreshListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lstLocations);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);


});

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {            
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    }
```

Comment: also post `first_fragment_layout.xml` file

Comment: besides your error: you may use [Naver's version of Pull to refresh](https://github.com/naver/android-pull-to-refresh) created on base of Chris Banes abbadoned lib. there is some fixes and new features, works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
 PullToRefreshListView list = (PullToRefreshListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lstLocations);
```

to

```
 PullToRefreshListView list = (PullToRefreshListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstLocations);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed out below line :-

```
ListView actualListView = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();
```

Without above line your pull to refresh not works.

see below link for more info :-

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/sample/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/samples/PullToRefreshListActivity.java